# How do I use custom-styled select menus on JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

I saw [some beautiful select menus](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html), apparently generated with JQuery with the following script:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```

When I tried the script, it simply produced default select menus without the JQuery custom styling. I suppose this makes sense, but how do I specify I want the above code to use the custom styling I found in the above link?

Note: I eventually want my software to go mobile, but I don't think I'm actually using JQuery Mobile right now; I may have just imported the standard JQuery UI, which may or may not include the custom-styling for all I know. I've also looked at other related questions, but didn't understand the answers.

Comment: Silly question: but did you include the jQuery mobile files?

Comment: You've answered your own question in the `Note:`

Comment: probably you don't have jQuery included. Can you give the entire code?

Comment: Have you tried including jQuery Mobile before running to SO and asking this question? Why do your expect it to work if you don't include the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you are not including jQuery Mobile, that means no awesome-select-menus for you! You do not have to programmatically create the styled-select-menu, jQuery Mobile will do it automatically if you include the jQuery Mobile files.

Both the JS and CSS files for jQuery Mobile need to be included in your pages:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/download/*

Note that jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI are completely different libraries; although both of them require the jQuery Core.

Comment: If you want to use only some or one of the widget(s) from jQuery Mobile you can tell the framework to only initialize specific widgets, here are the docs for doing this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Sounds awesome! But can I do it and still preserve elements I have already built just using the standard JQuery UI, such as sliders, themes, and styling? When I tried importing the mobile JS and CSS, I saw something for a split second and then it disappeared?

Comment: @BrianSchmitz There is just way too much to be able to answer here. jQuery Mobile has a bit of a learning curve; what you want to do is read the documentation for jQuery Mobile to familiarize yourself, there are some basic `Page Structure` docs that will get you started: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Comment: Or better yet can I apply the mobile stuff strictly to the selection menus? Or would I need to avoid the standard JQuery UI and build it in JQuery mobile from the ground up in order to make it compatible with mobile devices for the long term?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons your select lists might not be getting styled by the jquery library.  First, make certain the jquery libraries are all loaded - check with firebug http://getfirebug.com/ - or the google chrome inspector.
Make sure you've got the css loaded from the above demo.

One thing that that might be causing the issue - if those html elements are defined before jquery has access to them, then the script will not be able to find them.  Make sure to put the javascript code in a $(function() { (your javascript) } ); or put it at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag.

It would help if you post what you have either on a temporary site or http://jsfiddle.net/ - its hard to say what's going wrong without a little more information.